# Parsing and Storing the text data from webpage to database

Tags: html, oracle-apex-5

I have an web-service, where through URL I get the data in `text format`.

Is there any way to get the data from website and store it the database through PLSQL?

This how data is available in the website.

**DATA format:**

`locationId|locationName|city|state|postalCode|countryCode|regionId|
 9|DELHI, DEL-BLDG01|DELHI|DEL|111000|IND|1|`

Thank you.